On the solutions of $\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=a$
Context: Given
$$ f(x) = \frac {\ln(x)} {x} \; $$
For $a\in\mathbb R$, if the equation $f(x) = a$ has two solutions points $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, i.e.
$$f(x_{1}) =f(x_{2}) = a$$

Calculate the range of $a$.
Prove that $$x_{1} + x_{2} > \frac{2}{a}$$

Attempt: it is easy to show that $a$ is in $\left(0, \frac{1}{e}\right)$. For 2., I denoted $$g(x):=f(x)-a$$
and introduced
$$F(x):=g(x) - g\left(\frac{2}{a} - x\right)$$
But I could not tell that $F(x)$ is increasing or decreasing because that it is complicated.

What is $g(x)$ for you to use the word "Since"? If it was "Define" or "Let", then that statement would make more sense.

Also, proving $x_1 + x_2 > a/2$ is very very loose, since $ x_1 + x_2 > \max (x_1, x_2) > e  \approx 2.718 >   \frac{1}{2e} \approx 0.184 >  a / 2$.  I'm guessing something was copied incorrectly.

Suggestion for tags: You may use more tags for more audience. You may add "inequality" etc. Sometimes "real analysis".

@CalvinLin I think it might be $\frac 2a$

@Gwen@CalvinLin Sorry, it should be $\frac{2}{a}$

@RiverLi thanks for your tips

My third solution. Proceeding along OP's lines
It suffices to prove that $x_2 > \frac{2}{a} - x_1$. It suffices to prove that
$g(2/a - x_1) > g(x_2)$.
Using $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$ and $a = \frac{\ln x_1}{x_1}$, it suffices to prove that $g(2x_1/\ln x_1 - x_1) > g(x_1)$ for all $1 < x_1 < \mathrm{e}$,
i.e.
$$\frac{\ln \left(\frac{2x_1}{\ln x_1} - x_1\right)}{\frac{2x_1}{\ln x_1} - x_1} > \frac{\ln x_1}{x_1},$$
or
$$\ln \left(\frac{2x_1}{\ln x_1} - x_1\right) > 2 - \ln x_1, $$
or
$$\frac{2x_1}{\ln x_1} - x_1 > \frac{\mathrm{e}^2}{x_1},$$
or
$$\frac{2x_1}{x_1 + \frac{\mathrm{e}^2}{x_1}} > \ln x_1$$
which is true (easy, by taking derivative).
We are done.

$$\frac{2x_1}{x_1 + \frac{\mathrm{e}^2}{x_1}} > \ln x_1$$
which is true (easy, by taking derivative)
How to take derivative to get the final formula is true, could you elaborate more?

Let $F(x_1) := \frac{2x_1}{x_1 + \frac{\mathrm{e}^2}{x_1}} - \ln x_1$. We have $F(\mathrm{e}) = 0$. Also, we have $F'(x_1) = - \frac{(x_1^2 - \mathrm{e}^2)^2}{(x_1^2 + \mathrm{e}^2)^2 x_1}\le 0$. Thus, $F(x_1) \ge 0$ for all $1 < x_1 < \mathrm{e}$.

Let me calculate it later, looks great!

https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B2x%7D%7Bx%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%7Be%7D%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7Bx_%7B%20%7D%7D%7D%20-%20%5Cln%20x_%7B%20%7D%5Cright)
I use this website to calculate it.
May I ask if you use the similar to get that? Which idea leads you to this formula, and be sure that the derivatives is sure to be <=0 or >=0, it is really magic to me.

I use Maple, Mathematica, Matlab, or https://www.wolframalpha.com/.

I am using Macbook , do you use Macbook as a laptop? If Maple, Mathematica, Matlab has a version for Mac? I am tryting to install them or I can use a online website?

@FrancisBacon I don't know. You can use online solver such as the one you mentioned, or wolfrmalpha.com.

Mind my asking what you are using? Maple, Mathematica, Matlab installed on Windows?

@FrancisBacon Yes.

I used the wolframalpha.com to calculate the deriatives. Later will install Maple and others on my Mac.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%5Cfrac%5C%28123%292Subscript%5Bx%2C1%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%29Subscript%5Bx%2C1%5D+%2B+%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29Power%5B%5Cmathrm%5C%28123%29e%5C%28125%29%2C2%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%29Subscript%5Bx%2C1%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28125%29+-+%5Cln+Subscript%5Bx%2C1%5D

You see,$\frac{\ln x}{x}=0$ has a solution at $x=1$, but
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x}=0$$which means we'll get two $x$ values for one $f(x)$ value until we reach the maxima, which is at $x=e$.
$$a\in (f(1),f(e)) \implies a\in (0,\frac 1e)$$
This also gives us some valuable data, including the fact that $1<x_1<x_2$(I've assumed $x_1<x_2$)
Second part( considering $\frac a2$)
$x_2>x_1>1>a\implies x_1+x_2>\frac a2$
Second part (considering $\frac 2a$)
We can define $g(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}-a$, and then use the inequality
$$\int_1^{x_1} g(x) dx<\int_1^{x_2} g(x) dx$$
This gives $$\frac{\ln^2 x_1}{2}-ax_1<\frac{\ln^2 x_2}{2} - ax_2$$
We use the fact that $$\ln^2 x_2=\frac{x_2^2}{x_1^2} \ln ^2x_1$$
To get
$$\frac{\ln ^2 x_2}{2}\bigg(\frac{x_2^2-x_1^2}{x_2^2}\bigg)>a(x_2-x_1)$$
Which is $$\frac{a^2}{2}(x_1+x_2)>a$$
$$\implies (x_1+x_2)>\frac{2}{a}>\frac a2$$as $a<1$

When you get $$\frac{\ln ^2 x_2}{2}\bigg(\frac{x_2^2-x_1^2}{x_2^2}\bigg)>a(x_2-x_1)$$
How do you reason out $$\frac{a^2}{2}(x_1+x_2)>a$$??

@FrancisBacon $$\frac{\ln ^2 x_2}{x_2^2}=a^2= (f(x_2))^2$$ other than that it's just simple $x_2^2-x_1^2=(x_2-x_1)(x_2+x_1)$

@Gwen It is a nice way. I wonder if it works from some similar problems (e.g. the other problems of the same author).

@RiverLi No way like you're such a genius regarding inequalities and you found my method nice :") This made my day. I've an exam tomorrow sadly, I'll definitely try other problems out

@Gwen Feel free to do it.  Good luck. (I often provide complicated proofs of inequalities.)

@FrancisBacon ? Was my explanation clear in the reply?

@Gwen thanks, your reply is quite clear. Maybe you can find a union way to solve other question I posted, when you are available, thanks ahead.

Alternative solution.
Let $g(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x}$. We have $g'(x) = \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$. $g(x)$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \mathrm{e})$, and strictly decreasing on $(\mathrm{e}, \infty)$, and $g(\mathrm{e}) = \mathrm{e}^{-1}$,
and $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} g(x) = -\infty$,
and $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = 0$.
If $0 < a < \mathrm{e}^{-1}$, $g(x) = a$ has exactly two positive real solutions $0 < x_1 < \mathrm{e} < x_2$. We need to prove that $x_1 + x_2 > \frac{2}{a}$.
Let $h(x) := \frac{3x - \mathrm{e}}{x(x + \mathrm{e})}$. It is easy to prove that
$$g(x) - h(x) \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
 > 0 & x > \mathrm{e} \\
 = 0 & x = \mathrm{e} \\
 < 0 & 0 < x < \mathrm{e}.
\end{array}
\right. \tag{1}$$
Also, $h(x)$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \mathrm{e})$, and strictly decreasing on $(\mathrm{e}, \infty)$,
and $h(\mathrm{e}) = \mathrm{e}^{-1}$, and $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} h(x) = -\infty$, and $\lim_{x\to \infty} h(x) = 0$.
Thus, if $0 < a < \mathrm{e}^{-1}$,
$h(x) = a$ has exactly two positive real solutions $0 < x_3 < \mathrm{e} < x_4$. Furthermore,  from (1), we have $x_3 \le x_1$ and $x_4 \le x_2$.
Thus, $x_1 + x_2 \ge x_3 + x_4$. It suffices to prove that $x_3 + x_4 > \frac{2}{a}$.
We have
$$h(x) = a \iff x^2 - (3/a - \mathrm{e})x + \mathrm{e}/a = 0.$$
Since $x_3, x_4$ are the two positive real solutions of the quadratic equation $x^2 - (3/a - \mathrm{e})x + \mathrm{e}/a = 0$, we have
$$x_3 + x_4 = 3/a - \mathrm{e} > \frac{2}{a}$$
where we use $0 < a < \mathrm{e}^{-1}$.
We are done.

How do you come up with the h(x), is there any tricks to think of that?

@FrancisBacon Consider the Pade-(1,1) approximation of $\ln x$ at $x=\mathrm{e}$:  $\quad$ $p(x) := \frac{3x - \mathrm{e}}{(x + \mathrm{e})}$. Then $h(x) = \frac{p(x)}{x}$.

Thanks, but I still did not get it 100%. Maybe due to not clear about Pade-(1,1) approximation? Could you give me a link about it? Or any textbook?

@FrancisBacon E.g. https://math.gsu.edu/xye/course/na_handout/slides/other_fit.pdf#:~:text=Rational%20function%20approximation.%20Rational%20function%20of

let me digest it.

My second solution.
Let $k := \frac{x_2}{x_1} > 1$. Then $x_2 = kx_1$. We have
$$\ln x_1 = ax_1, \tag{1}$$
and
$$\ln (kx_1) = a kx_1. \tag{2}$$
$(2) - (1)$ gives $\ln k = a(k - 1)x_1 = (k-1)\ln x_1$ (using (1)), which results in
$x_1 = \mathrm{e}^{\frac{\ln k}{k-1}}$. Then $x_2 = k\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\ln k}{k-1}}$.
Also, we have $a = \frac{\ln x_1}{x_1} = \frac{\ln k}{k - 1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln k}{k-1}}$.
It suffices to prove that
$$\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\ln k}{k-1}} + k\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\ln k}{k-1}} \ge \frac{2(k-1)}{\ln k}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\ln k}{k-1}},$$
or
$$\ln k \ge \frac{2(k-1)}{k+1}$$
which is true (easy).
We are done.

This seems the simplist way to prove it.
Actually, it seems the same way to the final solution. Using Arithmetic-Logarithmic-Geometric Mean Inequality to prove it.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arithmetic-Logarithmic-GeometricMeanInequality.html

You are so awesome!!!

@FrancisBacon Nice A-L-G Mean inequ.
